# How to arange a heatmap and an scaterplot one above the other in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap, reshape

I am a newbie using ggplot2 and I'm trying to plot a scatter plot above a heatmap. Both plots have the same discrete x-axis.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(reshape2)
#data for the scatterplot

df = data.frame(id1 = letters[1:10], C = abs(rnorm(10)))

#scatter plot 
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x= id1, y = C)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 19) + theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = letters[1:10]) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

#data for the heatmap
X = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10))
names(X) = month.name[1:10]
X = melt(cbind(id1 = letters[1:10], X))

#heatmap 
p2 <- ggplot(X,
             aes(x = id1, y = variable, fill = value))
p2 <- p2 + geom_tile()
p2 <- p2 + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "white" , "red"))
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = letters[1:10])
p2 <- p2 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))

layt <- grid.layout(nrow=2,ncol=1,heights=c(2/8,6/8),default.units=c('null','null'))

vplayout <- function(x,y) {viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)}

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=layt))
print(p1,vp=vplayout(1,1))
print(p2,vp = vplayout(2,1))
```

The problem is that the axis are not situated one above the other.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=81975edabc&view=att&th=13ece12a06a3cea2&attid=0.1&disp=emb&realattid=ii_13ece128398baede&zw&atsh=1

Is there any solution? It is possible to reshape the data and make something like facets?

Comment: I'd try the `grid.extra` package, but aligning axes like this is always difficult. You may want to consider different visualizations (i.e. include the legend in your heatmap so you can avoid the need for a scatter plot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of tricks here. The first is that the tick marks get treated differently, even though you have the same discrete axis. When you do `expand = c(0,0)`, on the scatterplot the tick is now aligned with the `y` axis, while on the heatmap it is in the centre of the category. My method of getting around that is to manually assign the `expand` value for the scatterplot so that there is a gap of of 1/2 a categorical value. Because there are 10 categorical values, in this case it is `0.05` (`(1/10)/2`). The points will now align with the centre of each category.

The other side of the problem is because the `y` labels are different sizes they throw out the rest of the alignment. The solution comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016995/how-to-align-multiple-ggplot2-plots-and-add-shadows-over-all-of-them), using `ggplot_gtable` and `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package.

```
library(gridExtra)
#data for the scatterplot

df = data.frame(id1 = letters[1:10], C = abs(rnorm(10)))

#scatter plot 
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x= id1, y = C)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 19) + theme_bw() + 
# Change the expand values
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.05, 0.05), breaks = letters[1:10]) +
  #scale_y_discrete(breaks = NULL) +

  theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p1
#data for the heatmap
X = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10))
names(X) = month.name[1:10]
X = melt(cbind(id1 = letters[1:10], X))

#heatmap 
p2 <- ggplot(X,
             aes(x = id1, y = variable, fill = value))
p2 <- p2 + geom_tile()
p2 <- p2 + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "white" , "red"))
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = letters[1:10])
p2 <- p2 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))

#Here's the gtable magic
gp1<- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gp2<- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
#This identifies the maximum width
maxWidth = unit.pmax(gp1$widths[2:3], gp2$widths[2:3])
#Set each to the maximum width
gp1$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
gp2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
#Put them together
grid.arrange(gp1, gp2)
```

---

EDIT - See @baptiste's answer for a more elegant method of alignment of the `y` axis

[image]

Comment: you could [use `ggplotGrob`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880/471093) instead of `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build())`

Comment: Thank you, alexwhan for taking the time to answer me.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
grid.draw(gtable:::rbind.gtable(ggplotGrob(p1),
                                ggplotGrob(p2), size='last'))
```

(ideally one would want `size=max`, but it has a bug preventing it to work).

Comment: Definitely more elegant method to align the plots - I'll use it a lot! I think what makes this question different though is the alignment within the plots (because of the different `geom` in each), even if the left is aligned, the points will still not match the heatmap clearly.

Comment: the two alignment methods are virtually equivalent; only by working out the width manually you can use `unit.pmax`, which currently gtable:::rbind fails to do properly (you therefore need to guess which plot takes more space, hoping it's the same one across all viewports...)

Comment: Thank you very much, baptiste... Just a last question, I forgot to mention that I need that the heatmap uses more than the lower half of the plot (maybe 2/5, 3/5). I don't want to steal more of your time, but where I can find information to know how to do it??  And thank you again...

Comment: in my opinion you should rather accept @alexwhan answer as it is currently better, if slightly less compact. Using grid.arrange at the end, you can use `heights = c(2,3)` and that should work.