# Shrink and Align plots with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three plots and I would like to stack them, shrink the bottom 2, and make sure they are vertically aligned.  I can do one or the other, but not both.  As you can see in plot 1, the plots are vertically aligned, but I need to shrink the bottom two; and in plot 2, the bottom two have been shrunk, but are not vertically aligned.

How can I shrink the bottom two plots and make sure all the plots are vertically aligned?

Here is an example:

**ggplot:**

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
a <- ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(y = carat, x = price)) + geom_line()
b <- ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar()
c <- ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = color)) + geom_bar()
```

**Plot 1:**

```
plot_grid(a, b, c, labels=c("", "", ""), ncol = 1, nrow = 3, align = "v")
```

[image]

**Plot 2:**

```
grid.arrange(a,b,c, ncol = 1, nrow = 3, widths = c(1), heights = c(1,.3,.3))
```

[image]

Comment: Marking as a possible duplicate. See [example #1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13294952/2572423), [example #2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13656642/2572423), and [example #3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15016995/2572423).

Comment: Please include all `library` statements when posting a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `rel_heights` argument:

```
plot_grid(a, b, c, ncol = 1, align = "v", rel_heights = c(3, 1, 1))
```

Comment: That was the argument I was looking for.  Thanks!