# How can reference lines or objects be annotated across two different `ggplot` objects?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, annotations

Using `ggplot2`, I have two vertically aligned `geom_line()` objects and I want to draw a vertical rectangle across both plots in the same `x_axis` range.

For example, how could this rectangle be extended down across the plot below?

```
paquetes <- c("ggplot2", "gcookbook", "cowplot")
lapply(paquetes, require, character.only = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(subset(climate, Source=="Berkeley"), aes(x=Year, y=Anomaly10y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=1950, xmax=1980, ymin=-1, ymax=1, alpha=.1,
             fill="blue") +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

w <- ggplot(subset(climate, Source=="NASA"), aes(x=Year, y=Anomaly1y)) +
  geom_line()


both <- cowplot::plot_grid(p + theme(legend.position = "none"),
                                w + theme(legend.position = "none"),
                                align = "v",
                                ncol = 1,
                                nrow = 2)

both
```

[image]

Comment: maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016995/how-to-align-multiple-ggplot2-plots-and-add-shadows-over-all-of-them

Comment: Also, your example is not reproducible since we don't have `climate`.